# iOS check table cell Button while user Select or Deselect cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, checkbox

Actually I am creating collection of entries using User input. where i want to used Check Box for selection and diselection. instead of checkbox i have used Button where when user select on cell Button image get changed, but when one select again on that cell Nothing Happen. I have tried this.

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if([[cell.btn backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal]isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"]])
        {
            [cell.btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

And in didDeselectRowAtIndexPath

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([[cell.btn backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal]isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"]])
    {
         [cell.btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
}
```

Please Help me out where i am stucking.

Comment: Have you add console logs to check whether the control is entering the desired braces.... if yes... then what was the result ?

Comment: Please check the flow of control.. whether the control is going in the desired functions and the braces of control.

Comment: @Narendra create a class level NSinteger variable and save this instead of cell.selected yes/no.like currentIndex=indexPath.row. And in cellForRowAtIndex method check if indexPath.row == currentIndex then show slected image otherwise unselected image – Muhammad Adnan 1 min ago   edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set property of cell

when you select the cell.
`cell.selected = YES;`

and when you deselect the cell then 
`cell.selected = NO;`

if your tableview reload than you have to do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Method

because when you reload the table than you have to remember the cell selection state.

In your code there is never called tableView `didDeselect`  method

`didDeselect` only called when your tapped cell is selected.

Hope this will helps you

Answer (score 1):

```
  You must be using data object whose data is used to show in table view just add one property in it isSelected . Lets name the array as "data".




 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            [data objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]].isSelected=YES;
            [tableView reloadData];//or just row
        }

    And in didDeselectRowAtIndexPath
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [data objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]].isSelected=NO;
        [tableView reloadData];//or just row
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        //initial code

        //addd this code
        if([data objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]].isSelected){
          //set checked image 
        }else {
          //set unchecked image
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the code in setting the bool value...both on selection and the deselction you are doing the same thing

Comment: it's not working, actually i need to update checkbox when one clicked again on that cell, it's only work for first time and last cell get checked not first when i click on first..

Comment: and one interesting thing is when i scroll Horizontally and select last cell then first cell get selected..

Comment: i hope you are using [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] to get the cell that is selected or deselected